# How to remove an individual text node in a div without removing all of them?

Tags: javascript, dom, textnode

How do I go about removing an individual dynamically created text node?

I am generating input's on the fly and am using .createTextNode to place descriptive text before the elements.  I need the ability to delete specific elements that are being created and am using .removeChild to do it.  That works fine for removing an individual input because I have something to reference (id/name).  Is there a way to set some sort of reference to each text node so I can delete it along with its corresponding input control?

```
var box = document.getElementById("myDiv");

box.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Status: '));
var inp = document.createElement('input');
inp.type = 'text';
// add attributes, etc...

box.appendChild(inp);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why not wrap both in a fieldset to begin with?

```
var box = document.getElementById("myDiv");

var field = document.createElement('fieldset');
field.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Status: '));
var inp = document.createElement('input');
inp.type = 'text';
// add attributes, etc...

field.appendChild(inp);
box.appendChild(field);
```

This way just removing the field element will remove both your textnode and your input at the same time.

Comment: I actually like this answer better than my own.  Particularly in a form, there's no good reason to have text nodes that aren't inside fieldset/label elements.

Comment: Thanks for this, but I have a question.  How do I pass 'field' to a function so I can remove the fieldset?  I am creating a button that calls a function that when clicked deletes the field.  But this button is being created within the field itself and when I pass field to it, field is null.

Answer (score 4):

Keep reference to it:

```
var txt = document.createTextNode('Status: ');
box.appendChild(txt);
```

and then remove with:

```
txt.parentNode.removeChild(txt);
```

If node is supposed to be immediately before the input, this will work as well:

```
inp.parentNode.removeChild(inp.previousSibling);
```

It should work if you don't use `innerHTML` or `normalize()`, which could cause nodes to be re-created or merged, invalidating your references.

In case you wanted to remove arbitrary text from a node, there's `textnode.splitText(offset)`.

Answer (score 1):

Do not remove text nodes that are part of a list of textnodes in the DOM. Even if you reference them (before you appended them to the DOM).

The browser may merge multiple text nodes! I am not sure what the standards state, but its possible - at least some experience told me.. (may be old browsers, but it was the case).

Instead of that, you could either wrap each text node in a span or div tag, or you could use some kind of text replacements. I'd prefer the former.

Answer (score 0):

If you change this line:

```
box.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Status: '));
```

To:

```
var textNode = document.createTextNode('Status: ');
box.appendChild(textNode);
```

Then you can refer to the textNode var later to delete it. Be careful, though--some browsers will merge adjacent text nodes.

Answer (score 0):

```
var box = document.getElementById("myDiv");

var label = document.createTextNode('Status: ')
box.appendChild(label);
var inp = document.createElement('input');
inp.type = 'text';
// add attributes, etc...

box.appendChild(inp);

// do other stuff

//remove the label
label.nodeValue = "";
```